# Get Evenly Spaced Points from a Curved Shape

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve

How may I take a shape that was created with more points at its curves and subdivide it so that the points are distributed more equally along the curve? In my research I thought that `numpy`'s [interp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) might be the right function to use, but I don't know what to use for the parameters (`x`, `xp`, `fp`, `left`, `right`, & `period`). Any help would be very appreciated!

Here is an animation showing the desired output.

[image: Example of Shape with Even Distribution]

This is the code for the input rounded rectangle:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_values = [1321.4, 598.6, 580.6, 563.8, 548.6, 535.4, 524.5, 516.2, 511,
509.2, 509.2, 511, 516.2, 524.5, 535.4, 548.6, 563.8, 580.6, 598.6, 1321.4, 1339.4,
1356.2, 1371.4, 1384.6, 1395.5, 1403.8, 1409, 1410.8, 1410.8, 1409, 1403.8, 1395.5,
1384.6, 1371.4, 1356.2, 1339.4, 1321.4]
y_values = [805.4, 805.4, 803.5, 798.3, 790.1,
779.2, 766, 750.8, 734, 716, 364, 346, 329.2, 314, 300.8, 289.9, 281.7, 276.5, 274.6,
274.6, 276.5, 281.7, 289.9, 300.8, 314, 329.2, 346, 364, 716, 734, 750.8, 766, 779.2,
790.1, 798.3, 803.5, 805.4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x_values,y_values)
ax.scatter(x_values,y_values)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1321.4, 598.6, 580.6, 563.8, 548.6, 535.4, 524.5, 516.2, 511,
509.2, 509.2, 511, 516.2, 524.5, 535.4, 548.6, 563.8, 580.6, 598.6, 1321.4, 1339.4,
1356.2, 1371.4, 1384.6, 1395.5, 1403.8, 1409, 1410.8, 1410.8, 1409, 1403.8, 1395.5,
1384.6, 1371.4, 1356.2, 1339.4, 1321.4])
y = np.array([805.4, 805.4, 803.5, 798.3, 790.1,
779.2, 766, 750.8, 734, 716, 364, 346, 329.2, 314, 300.8, 289.9, 281.7, 276.5, 274.6,
274.6, 276.5, 281.7, 289.9, 300.8, 314, 329.2, 346, 364, 716, 734, 750.8, 766, 779.2,
790.1, 798.3, 803.5, 805.4])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.scatter(x, y, s=40, zorder=3, alpha=0.3)

# compute the distances, ds, between points
dx, dy = x[+1:]-x[:-1],  y[+1:]-y[:-1]
ds = np.array((0, *np.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)))

# compute the total distance from the 1st point, measured on the curve
s = np.cumsum(ds)

# interpolate using 200 point
xinter = np.interp(np.linspace(0,s[-1], 200), s, x)
yinter = np.interp(np.linspace(0,s[-1], 200), s, y)

# plot the interpolated points
ax.scatter(xinter, yinter, s=5, zorder=4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Incredible, thank you!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Dear @Dr.Pontchartrain, I won't say "Incredible", but some enthusiastic appreciation  is always welcome! thank you.

Comment: I have a follow-up question if you are able. If not, no worries: I'm super-grateful!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75416994/maintaining-sharp-corners-in-a-numpy-interpolation

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with the [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library. You can use your points to make a [`LineString`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.LineString.html#shapely.LineString) object, and then interpolate that using `numpy.linspace` like you expected.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely

x_values = [1321.4, 598.6, 580.6, 563.8, 548.6, 535.4, 524.5, 516.2, 511,
509.2, 509.2, 511, 516.2, 524.5, 535.4, 548.6, 563.8, 580.6, 598.6, 1321.4, 1339.4,
1356.2, 1371.4, 1384.6, 1395.5, 1403.8, 1409, 1410.8, 1410.8, 1409, 1403.8, 1395.5,
1384.6, 1371.4, 1356.2, 1339.4, 1321.4]
y_values = [805.4, 805.4, 803.5, 798.3, 790.1,
779.2, 766, 750.8, 734, 716, 364, 346, 329.2, 314, 300.8, 289.9, 281.7, 276.5, 274.6,
274.6, 276.5, 281.7, 289.9, 300.8, 314, 329.2, 346, 364, 716, 734, 750.8, 766, 779.2,
790.1, 798.3, 803.5, 805.4]

coords = np.array([x_values, y_values]).T

poly = shapely.LineString(coords)

coords_new = poly.interpolate(np.linspace(0, 1, num=51), normalized=True)

x_new = [pt.x for pt in coords_new]
y_new = [pt.y for pt in coords_new]

plt.plot(x_new, y_new)
plt.scatter(x_new, y_new)
plt.show()
```

[image: interpolated polygon]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, Roy! Unfortunately I won't have access to `shapely` (it's exactly what I need though!). Is there anything similar in `numpy` or `scipy`? Or can I find the `LineString` function somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: @Dr. Pontchartrain, I'm sure there's a way to use numpy/scipy to suit your needs. The problem I'm struggling with is that while you need evenly spaced points along a coordinate `t` that parameterizes your rectangle, `numpy.interp` and `scipy.interp1d` would be more suited to giving you evenly spaced points along the independent variable `x`. I haven't found an easy way to resolve this issue yet.

Comment: I truly appreciate the effort, Roy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very rudimental solution, where you interpolate between the neighbouring points on a line.

Basically what the code does is, that it places "temporary" points on the line between the neighbour points evenly spaced with approximately `stepsize` spacing. This will result in an approximately even spacing on the curve (the smaller the `stepsize` the denser the more points you have). Now if you pick every `skipper`-th point on it, the spacing between those points will be approx `skipper*stepsize`.

There is a small flaw in it, the first and the last points are not guaranteed to be this far from eachother, so you have to play with the `skipper` to fix that.

The code:

```
stepsize = 10**-2

new_x = np.array([])
new_y = np.array([])

for i in range(len(x_values)):
    x0 = x_values[i]
    x1 = x_values[(i+1)%len(x_values)]
    y0 = y_values[i]
    y1 = y_values[(i+1)%len(x_values)]

    dx = x1-x0
    dy = y1-y0

    length = np.sqrt(dx**2+dy**2)
    N = int(length/stepsize)

    new_x = np.append(new_x,np.linspace(x_values[i],x_values[(i+1)%len(x_values)],N))
    new_y = np.append(new_y,np.linspace(y_values[i],y_values[(i+1)%len(x_values)],N))

skipper = 6650

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x_values,y_values)
ax.scatter(new_x[::skipper],new_y[::skipper])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the message & code. Will this look as even with different shapes? Could you please explain the difference between `stepsize` & `skipper`?

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain it  in a bit more detail. Feel free to ask if you still have questions!

And yes, it would look even-ish with any kind of shapes. But bgoffi's answer is much better!